# Laptop screen won't turn on unless I plug in external monitors (Ubuntu / NVIDIA)

Tags: x11, nvidia, gnu-screen, display, monitors

When I installed my Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS I had it connected to 2 external monitors *(at the time of installation)*. Now every time I reboot my computer, my laptop screen is off. I need to connect it to my external monitors for the laptop screen to turn on. If I disconnect my monitors then the laptop's built-in display stays on just like it should. But if I then restart my computer the laptop screen won't turn on unless I plug in my external monitors.

It seems that at the installation my laptop got configured somehow in such a way that it requires external monitors at startup or something, I don't know. Is there a way I can fix this somehow? Because when I'm away from my monitors, my laptops is unusable.

My laptop is a Lenovo Legion 7:

```
Model: Lenovo Lenovo Legion 7 15IMH05
Memory: 32GB
Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-10750H CPU @ 2.60GHz × 12
Graphics: NVIDIA Corporation TU106BM [GeForce RTX 2070 Mobile]
Disk Capacity: 2.0 TB

OS Name: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
GNOME: 3.36.8
Windowing System: X11
```

Comment: Can you hot switch it back? Is the BIOS configured to consider the external monitor to be primary? Look at what `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` says.

Comment: And another thing... check the files in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` in case one of those files are forcing the output.